# How to deploy my Symfony3 project on a shared hosting - hostagator?

Tags: symfony

How to deploy my Symfony3 project on a shared hosting - hostagator? 
I have changed the `web` folder name to `public_html`. However, it only brings many complications. Is there any other way of doing so?
By the way, I know that I can put all the contents of my project in the `public_html` but it is very insecure and leaves my project easily exposed, so it is also not a good choice.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly:

- If problem is connected with hosting of given company - write message to support of this company.
- Better solution than shared hosting is vps. On vps you have full control and can configure it like you want.
- It is very bad practice to change `web` folder on `public_html`. Of course, you can, but after this a lot of symfony tools will be incompatible with your project.